# Can I erase my Mac hard drive and reinstall Lion (bought from the Mac App Store) to sell my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion

I've bought a new Mac laptop and I want to sell my Mac mini.
However, I need to erase my hard drive.

I only have the Snow Leopard install disk: I purchased Lion from the Mac App Store.

Is there any way I can install Lion? I don't want to put my Apple ID into the new install.
I'd rather leave it ready for my buyer.

When I go into Disk Utility, I don't see a restore partition, possibly because the Mac mini has an optical drive. Not sure if I can set up a restore partition. If I could, would I have to enter my Apple ID?

Comment: I suggest you just install Snow Leopard and let whom ever buys the computer upgrade it on their own.  Of course you could just create a boot USB/Disk yourself.

Comment: How do I create a boot disk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't have a resellable license to Lion, so you can't sell your machine with Lion installed.  Only sell it with an OS installed that you have right to resell.